# Simple question about wedge sum

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I have a silly question how the wedge sum, as described by Atcher, works.
In his book wedge sum is described as it follows:

> Given spaces $X$ and $Y$ with chosen points $x_0\in X$ and $y_0\in Y$ , then the wedge sum $X\vee Y$ is the quotient of the disjoint union $X\sqcup Y$ obtained by identifying $x_0$ and $y_0$ to a single point.

And this concept can be extended to

> [...] one could form the wedge sum $\bigvee_\alpha X_\alpha$ of an arbitrary collection of
> spaces $X_\alpha$ by starting with the disjoint union $\bigsqcup_\alpha X_\alpha$ and identifying points $x_\alpha\in X_\alpha$ to a single point.

My question is: does $X\vee Y\vee Z\simeq(X\vee Y)\vee Z$?
To be more clear, if I have the wedge sum between a space and a space "already wedged" where does the new identification is located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $(X \lor Y) \lor Z$ and $X \lor Y \lor Z$ (defined as the wedge sum of the family $\{X,Y,Z\}$) are naturally homeomorphic. This is maybe easiest to see as a general fact for colimits in categories. In the category of pointed spaces $\mathsf{pTop}$, with morphisms all base-point preserving continuous maps, the wedge sum of $\{(X_i, x_i)\mid i \in I\}$ is the colimit of  a diagram with just those spaces (and no morphisms). And such an ”associative law” for such colimits is IIRC a standard fact in categories.

As a set $(X \lor Y) \lor Z$ can easily be identified with the disjoint sum of $X,Y$ and $Z$ with base points identified. The two step nature of the two single identifications does not really matter for the end result.

Comment: Sorry for being late but I think that i need some clarification.
Am I missing something or what you said implies that a "clover shape" (the canonical $\bigvee_{i=1}^3 S^2$) is omotopic equivalent to three tangent sphere with their center on the same axes?

Comment: @Barbamento no, that’s not what follows from this. I don’t even mention homotopy equivalence.

Comment: Homeomorphism implies homotopy equivalnce between spaces, doesn't it?